# Flutter app use VoIP, SIP. Receive incoming call app close when app in background/terminated, ok in foreground

Tags: flutter, voip, callkit

I use [flutter_callkit_incoming](https://github.com/hiennguyen92/flutter_callkit_incoming) package to push call screen in my app. I use flutter 3.0.5, Xcode 14.3. In didReceiveIncomingPushWith method, I call from native to framework for push call screen. When app in background/terminated, app crash with log:

```
Apps receving VoIP pushes must post an incoming call (via CallKit or IncomingCallNotifications) in the same run loop as   pushRegistry:didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload:forType:[withCompletionHandler:] without delay.
*** Assertion failure in -[PKPushRegistry _terminateAppIfThereAreUnhandledVoIPPushes], PKPushRegistry.m:353
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception ‘NSInternalInconsistencyException’, reason: ‘Killing app because it never posted an incoming call to the system after receiving a PushKit VoIP push callback.’
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1a1127928 0x1b4ec6480 0x1a1035380 0x1a236def8 0x1c931570c 0x1a0d5f298 0x1a0d0e814 0x1c931474c 0x1a0d5e2b0 0x1a0d5f298 0x1a0d0dce0 0x1a10a6998 0x1a10a0df8 0x1a109fed0 0x1b77eb570 0x1a39cd2d0 0x1a39d284c 0x104cbd6ec 0x1a0d7e140)
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
* thread #1, queue = ‘com.apple.pushkit.ivarqueue’, stop reason = signal SIGABRT
    frame #0: 0x00000001ccf977b0 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 8
libsystem_kernel.dylib`:
->  0x1ccf977b0 <+8>:  b.lo   0x1ccf977cc               ; <+36>
    0x1ccf977b4 <+12>: stp    x29, x30, [sp, #-0x10]!
    0x1ccf977b8 <+16>: mov    x29, sp
    0x1ccf977bc <+20>: bl     0x1ccf741fc               ; cerror_nocancel
Target 0: (Runner) stopped.
```

In Apple Dev docs, I see  [pushRegistry:didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pushkit/pkpushregistrydelegate/2875784-pushregistry?language=objc): On iOS 13.0 and later, if you fail to report a call to CallKit, the system will terminate your app.
Any reply will be appreciated, thanks!

I try solved with native Swift follow readme file of package but it still doesn't work